# Copy title attribute from <a title=...> to clipboard in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url, url-shortening

On Twitter, users use short URLs (ie: http://t.co/DPbRAjVM).

The title attribute of the `<a href="..." title="...">` tag is the actual URL.

Is there a Chrome extension that you can use to copy the title to the clipboard which you can then paste into your browser window?  I am looking to get the actual URL and not click through to the URL shortener service.

Comment: By title, I am assuming you mean the `title=""` attribute in the `a` element. Is this correct?

Comment: @iglvzx, yes, that's it

Comment: I guess there's even a better solution: an extension or user script that actually changes the `href` for you, after the page has loaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension, if you are using Google Chrome: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unshortenit/lgmkbhnfldpklfakbcopgkkhonofficm

This extension if you are using Firefox: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unshortenit/

All you got to do is, right click on the URL that you want to unshorten and then select the option "Unshorten Link". That's it. You will get the unshortened URL, which shows the original location. Copy the URL to the clipboard from there.

I tried the Chrome extension, and am pretty sure that the Firefox extension also works similar to it.

Comment: Link for Chrome extension not working anymore ,I just found this other extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unshortenlink/gbobdaaeaihkghbokihkofcbndhmbdpd Works well, when you click on short links, new page opened with real url. You have the choice to go there or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the available Google Chrome extensions related to expanding URLS, they all seem to replace the `title` attribute, instead of the text in the `<a>` element. So, to expand on [@MasterMorbi](https://superuser.com/users/99137/matermorbi)'s answer, I have devised a workaround.

[image: Short URL]

- **Right click** the link, and select `Inspect element`.

  [image: Inspect element]
- The Developer Tools will pop-up, and the link's element (`<a>`) will be highlighted.

  [image: Developer tools]
- **Double click** to the right of `title="` in the element to select the URL.

  [image: Title attribute]
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the URL, and then press <kbd>F12</kbd> to close the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the `title` attribute just press CTRL + U and then search for the url in the code tab.

Comment: I'd like an easy way to copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: Eleven years later this need still exists and is still unmet apparently.