# Copy title attribute from the hovered element to clipboard

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/364029/copy-title-attribute-from-a-title-to-clipboard-in-chrome), but not limited to `<a...>` link elements; instead I want to copy the `title` attribute from an arbitrary element (usually a `TD` in my use case) to the clipboard.

I would be content either with a context menu choice, or a hotkey. Either way, the element that the mouse is directly on top of is the one I want to grab the title from.

In my use case, the site [Digicert](https://digicert.com) abbreviates "long" strings with an ellipsis and puts the whole string in a title. (Instead of [using CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/), which can do this for any string without needing to change the string, they actually emit
`<td title="very long string" class="text-xs-left">very lon...</td>`
I've told them there's a better way, but it remains this clunky way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tampermonkey chrome extension to do that,
here is script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ctrl + mouse-right-click to copy title from cloest element
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

;
(function() {
    'use strict';

let clickFn=(ev)=>{
    console.log(`begin copy title from cloest element ...`)
    if(ev.ctrlKey){
        ev.preventDefault()
    }else{
        console.log(` please hold down the Ctrl key`)
        return
    }
    let target=ev.target
    let v=""

    if(1){
        let pp=target
        let bb=document.body
        let distance=-1
        let attr='title'
        // attr='id'
        while(pp!==bb){
            distance++
            if(pp.hasAttribute(attr)){
                v=pp.getAttribute(attr)
                console.log(`dis:${distance}|tag:${pp.tagName}|title:${v}`)
                GM_setClipboard(v,"text")
                break
            }
            pp=pp.parentElement
        }
    }
    if(v){
        console.log(`copy title success`)
    }else{
        console.log(`title Not found`)
    }
}

//document.addEventListener("click",clickFn)
document.addEventListener("contextmenu",clickFn)

})();
```

### usage:

hold the ctrl key down,and press the mouse right-click key